# How to extract pre-defined key words from a sentence in Python?

Tags: python, nlp

Consider the following example
"10% of on all Artificial Intelligence courses."
In this example, I have to extract two predefined classes like Artificial Intelligence and courses. Even the program has to classify words like ANN, CNN, RNN, AI, etc. into the Artificial Intelligence category. I have used spacy to train but I am not impressed with the results as it is not labeling correctly. Is there any alternative to extract entities from a sentence in Python?

Comment: do you want only ML based approach for extracting pre defined category ????

Comment: Yes if possible or any easier method if available. Please suggest the steps that I need to follow

Comment: If you have found good solution apart from flashtext, share it so that it can help others

Answer (score 0):

Here are the few options that I would try out.

1.Custom entity extraction with Rasa.

```
https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/nlu/entity-extraction/#custom-entities
```

2. Bert based NER for Custom entities. Take a look at the following repositories

```
https://github.com/allenai/scibert
https://github.com/dmis-lab/biobert
```

Comment: But I am not able to follow the documentation. If you can help me with the steps to be followed. It would be great

Answer (score 0):

You can use flashtext for doing this.

```
from flashtext import KeywordProcessor

kp = KeywordProcessor()

# make a dictionary and create key , insert all keyword in one key (i.e CNN, ANN RNN will come under artificial Intelligence, whenever this value will appear it will extract key for you ) 
dict_= {'Artificial Intelligence': ['ANN','CNN','RNN','AI','Artificial Intelligence'],'courses' : ['courses']} 

kp.add_keywords_from_dict(dict_)

# here Artificial Intelligence, ANN and CNN come under Artificial Intelligence key , that why it will extract the tag as Artificial Intelligence
kp.extract_keywords('10% of on all Artificial Intelligence, ANN, and CNN courses.')
#op
['Artificial Intelligence',
 'Artificial Intelligence',
 'Artificial Intelligence',
 'courses']
```

for more information you can follow the documentation of flashtext https://readthedocs.org/projects/flashtext/downloads/pdf/latest/

Comment: If there is any NLP approach possible can you suggest?